# How use Gallery in fragment on Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm with problem for use Gallery in Fragment. Someone know help me ?
The problme is in line gallery.setAdapter(ad), when I do debugging.

Class Fragment03:

> public class Fragment03 extends Fragment {
>
> ```
>    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>           return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_03, container, false);
>
>    }
>
>            @Override 
>            public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
>            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);  
>
>            ArrayList<Integrantes_imagens> array = new ArrayList<Integrantes_imagens>();
>
>
>
>            array.add(new Integrantes_imagens(0));
>            array.add(new Integrantes_imagens(1));
>            array.add(new Integrantes_imagens(2));
>            array.add(new Integrantes_imagens(3));
>            array.add(new Integrantes_imagens(4));
>
>
>            //Log.i("Script:", "Imagem " + array.get(0));
>
>            //getActivity().setContentView(R.layout.displayview);
>
>            ArrayAdapter<Integrantes_imagens> ad = new    CustomAdapterIntegrantes(getActivity(),R.layout.displayview, array);
>            Gallery gallery = (Gallery) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gallery1); 
>            gallery.setAdapter(ad); 
>
>
>
>            gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
>                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
>                {
>
>                    //---display the images selected---
>                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.image1); 
>                    imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
>                } 
>            });
>
>        }  
>      }
> ```

Class CustomAdapterIntegrantes:

```
public class CustomAdapterIntegrantes extends ArrayAdapter<Integrantes_imagens>{

private final int resourceId;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapterIntegrantes(Context context, int resource, List<Integrantes_imagens> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.resourceId = resource;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Log.i("Script:", "Aqui3!!");

    // get the person from position
    Integrantes_imagens img = getItem(position);

    // get a new View no matter recycling or ViewHolder FIXME
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

    ImageView i = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageintegrante);

    if(img.getValor() == 0)
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem01);
    else if(img.getValor() == 1)
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem02);
    else if(img.getValor() == 2)
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem03);
    else if(img.getValor() == 3)
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem04);
    else if(img.getValor() == 4)
        i.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagem05);


    return convertView;
}


   }
```

Class Integrantes_imagens:

```
public class Integrantes_imagens {

    private int valor;

    public Integrantes_imagens(int valor){

        this.valor = valor;

    }

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }



}
```

Erro:

03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at com.isapps.fragment.Fragment03.onActivityCreated(Fragment03.java:71)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
03-22 20:54:53.390: E/AndroidRuntime(13179):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at com.isapps.fragment.Fragment03.onActivityCreated(Fragment03.java:71)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
03-22 20:56:03.510: E/AndroidRuntime(13271):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What is the error? Anything in logcat?

Comment: donfuxx, I inserted the erro.

Comment: you are searching `R.id.gallery` in the layout of the activity before the fragment is created, it can only work if the gallery not in the layout's fragment but sibling the container of the fragment, you probably want to use the inflated `R.layout.fragment_03`